# Windows Service relative path issue in Python

Tags: python, windows-services, exe, py2exe

I have written a small Windows Service compiled to an exe using py2exe, which from I read a file. It works great - however - I can only use an absolute path to access the file, using a relative path won't work. In .net you can do something like:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

To get the path to the .exe file, is there an option similar to this but for Python?

Best Regards,

Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  If you already have a module object, you can do `<module>.__file__` to get the path:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/time.so'
```

However, often times you want to know the location of your current module, in which case you can use:

```
import inspect

path = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename
```

(Also keep in mind that this can be anything that can be loaded by Python - so it can be a .pyd, .pyc, .so, .dll, etc.)

Comment: @martineau: They both work, it's just a question of what you have as input.  If you're in the module whose code you want to locate, you have to use the second one.

Comment: I looked at a standard module in python, for example, `json` used the first example, then did a split on `.exe` since that is included in the path. And everything before that is the relative path.